# Why is this less accurate when applying vggnet?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm interested in CNN. So, I want to use VGGnet in my code. Accuracy is only slightly increased when training. And When I applied simple CNN without applying vggnet, the accuracy was 82%. But when I apply vggnet, the accuracy drops to 74%.
I can not understand why a better algorithm is used and the accuracy is lowered. What am I doing wrong? Is vggnet unsuitable for my data? How can I solve this problem?
My dataset is medical image(Predicting IDC or non IDC)
Here is my code. I would appreciate your good advice.

---

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from glob import glob
import itertools

import fnmatch
import random
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
import cv2
from scipy.misc import imresize, imread
import sklearn
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold, cross_val_score, StratifiedKFold, learning_curve, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, make_scorer, accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import Callback, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential, model_from_json
from keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop, Adam, Adagrad, Adadelta
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, MaxPooling2D
%matplotlib inline

imagePatches = glob('../daeun/kaggle/input/IDC_regular_ps50_idx5/**/*.png', recursive=True)

image_name = "../work/kaggle/input/IDC_regular_ps50_idx5/9135/1/9135_idx5_x1701_y1851_class1.png" #Image to be used as query

patternZero = '*class0.png'
patternOne = '*class1.png'

classZero = fnmatch.filter(imagePatches, patternZero)
classOne = fnmatch.filter(imagePatches, patternOne)

print("IDC(-)\n\n",classZero[0:5],'\n')
print("IDC(+)\n\n",classOne[0:5])

def proc_images(lowerIndex,upperIndex):
    x = []
    y = []
    WIDTH = 50
    HEIGHT = 50
    for img in imagePatches[lowerIndex:upperIndex]:
        full_size_image = cv2.imread(img) 
        x.append(cv2.resize(full_size_image, (WIDTH,HEIGHT), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
        if img in classZero:
            y.append(0)
        elif img in classOne:
            y.append(1)
        else:
            return
    return x,y

X,Y = proc_images(0,90000)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["images"]=X
df["labels"]=Y
X2=df["images"]
Y2=df["labels"]
X2=np.array(X2)
imgs0=[]
imgs1=[]
imgs0 = X2[Y2==0] # (0 = no IDC, 1 = IDC)
imgs1 = X2[Y2==1]

dict_characters = {0: 'IDC(-)', 1: 'IDC(+)'}

X=np.array(X)
X=X/255.0

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)

X_train = X_train[0:300000] 
Y_train = Y_train[0:300000]
X_test = X_test[0:300000] 
Y_test = Y_test[0:300000]

Y_trainHot = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes = 2)
Y_testHot = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes = 2)

lab = df['labels']
dist = lab.value_counts()
sns.countplot(lab)
print(dict_characters)

X_trainShape = X_train.shape[1]*X_train.shape[2]*X_train.shape[3]
X_testShape = X_test.shape[1]*X_test.shape[2]*X_test.shape[3]
X_trainFlat = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_trainShape)
X_testFlat = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_testShape)

from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
ros = RandomUnderSampler(ratio='auto')
X_trainRos, Y_trainRos = ros.fit_sample(X_trainFlat, Y_train)
X_testRos, Y_testRos = ros.fit_sample(X_testFlat, Y_test)

Y_trainRosHot = to_categorical(Y_trainRos, num_classes = 2)
Y_testRosHot = to_categorical(Y_testRos, num_classes = 2)

for i in range(len(X_trainRos)):
    height, width, channels = 50,50,3
    X_trainRosReshaped = X_trainRos.reshape(len(X_trainRos),height,width,channels)

for i in range(len(X_testRos)):
    height, width, channels = 50,50,3
    X_testRosReshaped = X_testRos.reshape(len(X_testRos),height,width,channels)

dfRos = pd.DataFrame()
dfRos["labels"]=Y_trainRos
labRos = dfRos['labels']
distRos = lab.value_counts()
sns.countplot(labRos)
print(dict_characters)

def runKerasCNNAugment(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    batch_size = 128
    num_classes = 2
    epochs = 8
    img_rows,img_cols=50,50
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 3)
    base_model = VGG19(weights = 'imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 3))
    xx = base_model.output
    xx = Flatten()(xx)
    predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(xx)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    callbacks_list = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=3, verbose=1)]
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=20,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        width_shift_range=0.2,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.2,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=True)  # randomly flip images
    history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(a,b, batch_size=32),
                        steps_per_epoch=len(a) / 32, epochs=epochs,class_weight=f, validation_data = [c, d],callbacks = [MetricsCheckpoint('logs')])
    score = model.evaluate(c,d, verbose=0)
    print('\nKeras CNN #1C - accuracy:', score[1],'\n')
    y_pred = model.predict(c)
    map_characters = {0: 'IDC(-)', 1: 'IDC(+)'}
    print('\n', sklearn.metrics.classification_report(np.where(d > 0)[1], np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), target_names=list(map_characters.values())), sep='')    
    Y_pred_classes = np.argmax(y_pred,axis=1) 
    Y_true = np.argmax(d,axis=1) 

runKerasCNNAugment(X_trainRosReshaped, Y_trainRosHot, X_testRosReshaped, Y_testRosHot,2,class_weight2)
```

---

Here is my result

And result is here:

```
Epoch 1/8
1299/1298 [==============================] - 27s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5580 - acc: 0.7216 - val_loss: 0.5227 - val_acc: 0.7386
Epoch 2/8
1299/1298 [==============================] - 27s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5260 - acc: 0.7466 - val_loss: 0.5321 - val_acc: 0.7298
Epoch 3/8
1299/1298 [==============================] - 27s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5175 - acc: 0.7512 - val_loss: 0.5170 - val_acc: 0.7412
Epoch 4/8
1299/1298 [==============================] - 27s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5166 - acc: 0.7556 - val_loss: 0.5086 - val_acc: 0.7528
Epoch 5/8
1299/1298 [==============================] - 27s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5141 - acc: 0.7562 - val_loss: 0.5017 - val_acc: 0.7572
Epoch 6/8
1299/1298 [==============================] - 27s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5119 - acc: 0.7602 - val_loss: 0.5061 - val_acc: 0.7515
Epoch 7/8
1299/1298 [==============================] - 27s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5090 - acc: 0.7591 - val_loss: 0.4999 - val_acc: 0.7611
Epoch 8/8
1299/1298 [==============================] - 27s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5100 - acc: 0.7624 - val_loss: 0.5043 - val_acc: 0.7539

Keras CNN #1C - accuracy: 0.7538994800234126
```

---

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

What is possibly happening is that while the accuracy looks promising, no actual prediction is being made. What I mean by this is that the model might converge very quickly on a simple solution such as labeling everything as negative. This then leads to a reasonable accuracy, dependent on the data you are using, but says nothing.
I would suggest training the model and using it to predict a few images. Then turn the output back into human readable format, most likely a picture, and see if it predicted something or whether its all negative or positive labels.